# storing and rendering back php + html code into mysql problem

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am creating my own website I want to store some of my php variable + Html code into mysql database and want to use it for display. like

```
<a href="<?php echo $default_url;?>/link-to-page-1">page 1</a>
<a href="<?php echo $default_url;?>/link-to-page-2">page 2</a>
```

and simple storing it to mysql database

///////////////////

when displaying data first I fetch it using my own written PDO based select function (extra info)

first line

```
<?php $default_url="localhost/cms"; ?>  // initializing $default _url variable
```

2ns line

```
$body = select_body(); // returns above stored 

echo $body;
```

in source code it shows like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $default_url;?>/link-to-page-1">page 1</a>
<a href="<?php echo $default_url;?>/link-to-page-2">page 2</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="localhost/cms/link-to-page-1">page 1</a>
<a href="localhost/cms/link-to-page-2">page 2</a>
```

Comment: is your view file parsed by PHP?

Comment: Sir,
I'm fetching this

$body="<a href="localhost/cms/link-to-page-1">page 1</a>
<a href="localhost/cms/link-to-page-2">page 2</a>";

and echoing it like
echo $body;

or if I do it echo eval($body); 

it works fine until I'm using simple string like 

$string="me";

$body="hello this is $string";

echo eval($body);

but not working in this condition

<a href="$string">page1</a>

Comment: also tried

eval("\$body = \"$body\";");
echo $body;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before your way is a very [insecure way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951868/1847340). You should configure a [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule (in case you are running apache). That gives you the power to redirect any call from 
`localhost/link-to-page-1` to `localhost/cms/link-to-page-1` without storing insecure code in your database. For other webservers [similar plugins](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule) exist

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd store HTML and PHP in the database. Is this populated by yourself? If so, use `eval($code)`. But it's not the safest function, they can effectively do anything you can in code.

Comment: I'm creating a website with url= xyz.com and running my site from xyz.com/dir

now if I store my all links as <a href="xyz.com/dir/homepage.php">page 1</a> like this I cant change my site directory afterword due to huge number of hard codded urls placed in my other pages.

if I have a variables stored before my page name I can easily change value of variable it wuld be easy to change directory.... 

eval function is is working normally but under <a href=""></a> tag it showing same as I wrote before